# How can in modify value of dict in dict in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

So i have json which looks like:

```
{
  "Name": "test",
  "CreationDate": "2021-12-1",
  "Commands": [
    {
      "Command": "open",
      "Target": "Link To go ",
      "Value": "",
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "type",
      "Target": "name=emailOrPhone",
      "Value": "someEMAIL",
      "Targets": [
        "name=emailOrPhone",
        "xpath=//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input",
        "xpath=//input[@name='emailOrPhone']",
        "xpath=//input",
        "css=#react-root > section > main > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(4) > div > label > input"
      ],
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "type",
      "Target": "name=fullName",
      "Value": "NAme Last Name ",
      "Targets": [
        "name=fullName",
        "xpath=//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/div/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div/label/input",
        "xpath=//input[@name='fullName']",
        "xpath=//div[4]/div/label/input",
        "css=#react-root > section > main > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(5) > div > label > input"
      ],
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "type",
      "Target": "name=username",
      "Value": "USERNAME_HERE",
      "Targets": [
        "name=username",
        "xpath=//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/div/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div/label/input",
        "xpath=//input[@name='username']",
        "xpath=//div[5]/div/label/input",
        "css=#react-root > section > main > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(6) > div > label > input"
      ],
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "type",
      "Target": "name=password",
      "Value": "PASS_HERE",
      "Targets": [
        "name=password",
        "xpath=//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/div/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div/label/input",
        "xpath=//input[@name='password']",
        "xpath=//div[6]/div/label/input",
        "css=#react-root > section > main > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(7) > div > label > input"
      ],
      "Description": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

So how to edit values of email,username and passowrd ones?  Do i have to iterate over each Command dict? if so,how to find 'Command' that  have email field for example?
Because these dictionaries can be mixed and do not always follow each other

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Here is the solution.
Just need to iterate over each Command Dict.

```
for each in data["Commands"]:
    if each["Target"] == 'name=fullName' :
        each['Value'] = 'New Value'  # just updating the required value.
```